# How to conditionally display data in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have to display api returned data or No Data message. Below is my code in Vuejs:

```
<div v-if="resp.length > 0">
    <div>data displayed here from api</data>
</div>
<div v-else>
    No Data
</div>
```

Another approach I have tried:

```
<div v-show="resp.length > 0">
    <div>data displayed here from api</data>
</div>
<div v-show="resp.length === 0">
    No Data
</div>
```

Whether api returns data or not, "No Data" is getting displayed initially. If api returns data "No Data" disappears and actual data is shown. If no data from api, "No Data" stays.

Api data is getting loaded in beforeMount() lifecycle method. Any clue how to handle this? Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initially set default value false for isLoaded ,after the api data is loaded change the value of isLoaded to true

```
<div v-if="isLoaded">
 <div v-if="resp.length > 0">
    <div>data displayed here from api</data>
 </div>
 <div v-else>
    No Data
  </div>
</div>
<div v-else>
Loading
</div>
```